# variable declared as final within interface

Tags: java

I bet my java lecturer will be disappointed in me.

I think my Java/oop skills are alittle rusty. Why is the variable stateMachine being declared as final .

```
package com.example.accentag4.MessageType;

import android.view.View;

import com.example.accentag4.Model.StateMachine;

public interface MessageType
{
    StateMachine stateMachine = null;
    boolean process(String message);
    StateMachine GetState();
    void SetState(StateMachine stateIn);
}



public class HeartBeat implements MessageType {

    @Override
    public boolean process(String message) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public StateMachine GetState() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void SetState(StateMachine stateIn) {
        stateMachine=stateIn;
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm disappointed with myself nvm

Comment: A field in an interface is [by definition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.3) implicitly `public static final`.